# I/O reading from a file (python)

Tags: python, input, io, irc

Ok, I have an IRC bot and I have a file full of nicknames (which are the admins for the bot), for example if someone types "!op" in the channel how would I go about making the bot read the file to see if the user who typed "!op" is in the list of admins and if he is then proceed with the action.. I'm just confused on how to make it read the file for the authorized users.. Your help will be appreciate it. Thanks.

Can I use something like this..

```
      def isadmin(nick, 'masters.txt'):
      for admin in file:
          if nick == admin.rstrip():
              return True
      return False

     if data.find('!op') != -1:
     nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
     if nick == isadmin(nick, open('masters.txt')):
        sck.send('MODE ' + chan + ' +o ' + nick + '\r\n')
     else:
          sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + ' :' + ' youre not my master ' + '\r\n')
```

Answer (score 4):

You should probably just run through the whole [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).  There is a whole section about [reading and writing files](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: I know how to read from a file, I just dont know how to start, I need an example

Comment: Then you need to be more specific with what part is giving you trouble.

Comment: look at my code, so u can have an idea of what im trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

I assume your names are **line seperated**.

```
def isadmin(name, file):
    for admin in file:
        if name == admin.rstrip():
            return True
    return False
```

But they could also be **comma seperated**.

```
def isadmin(name, file):
    for admins in file:
        if name in admins.rstrip().split(","):
            return True
    return False
```

And use it like this:

```
isadmin("bob", open("admins.txt"))
```

Comment: can you explain more the line isadmin("bob", open("admins.txt"))

Comment: It sets name in both functions to "bob", the test subject, and open("admins.txt") opens a file "admins.txt" with read permissions and sets the `file` variable in `isadmin` to a file object pointing to "admins.txt" and then the `isadmin` function reads lines from it.

Comment: Can you check my code above, and tell me if thats the right way to do it.. thanks

Comment: The usage of my function is correct, I'm not sure about the other code (although you forgot to indent the body of the function correctly).

Answer (score 0):

```
admins = set(nick.strip() for nick in open('masters.txt'))

def isadmin(nick):
    return nick.strip() in admins
```

File reading is expensive enough that you don't want to re-read the file too often; if it's short, read it once and keep it in memory.